# Are there any pros to having a convolution layer using a filter the same size as the input data?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, convolution

Are there any pros to having a convolution layer using a filter the same size as the input data (i.e. the filter can only fit over the input one way)?

Answer (score 1):

A filter the same size as the input data will collapse the output dimensions to 
`1 x 1 x n_filters`, which could be useful towards the end of a network that has a low dimensional output like a single number for example.

One place this is used is in sliding window object detection, where redundant computation is saved by making only one forward pass to compute the output on all windows.

However, it is more typical to add one or more dense layers that give the desired output dimension instead of fully collapsing your data with convolution layers.